# Decrypting personal Address gives error asp.net

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I want to encrypt address in database, it saves with no exception, but when i decrypt address on load it gives error:

```
Unable to load information. Possible reason: Error in DecodeInvalid length for a Base-64 char array. 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="200px" />
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftxtAddress" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAddress"
FilterType="Custom,Numbers, LowercaseLetters" InvalidChars="!@#$%^&*()~`*-/+|\}{[]<>?" ValidChars=",.?-_ " />
```

I use:

```
public string Decode(string sData)
{
  try
  {
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

    byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(sData);
    int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
    char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
    utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
    string result = new String(decoded_char);
    return result;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception("Error in Decode" + e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you do the encoding?  Or give us a sample of the sData that gives the error?

Answer (score 1):

On the encoding side:

```
string rawText = "123 Any Street, Any City, Any State 99999, USA";
byte[] bytesE =  UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawText);
//If you have your encryption code and it outputs a byte array, pass that to bytesE
string sData = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesE);
```

*sData* will then be "MTIzIEFueSBTdHJlZXQsIEFueSBDaXR5LCBBbnkgU3RhdGUgOTk5OTksIFVTQQ==".  I assume you then store this in your database.

On the decoding side:

```
byte[] bytesD = Convert.FromBase64String(sData);
//If you have your decryption program, you now pass bytesD to it.
string address = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesD);
```

*address* will now be "123 Any Street, Any City, Any State 99999, USA"

*sData* must be a valid Base64 encoded string that is properly terminated, otherwise Convert.FromBase64String will produce an exception.

Remember, if you do not have your encryption code, the above provides **zero** security.

Comment: how do i validate that the string is base64 im still receiving error

Comment: how many character are allowed in base64 if i limit 36 character then no error

Comment: To validate, use try and catch!

Comment: Are you trying to encode to base64 yourself?  If so, you need to refer to the specs, either http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 or RFC 4648.  If your data is already an array of bytes, just use UTF8ENcoding.UTF8.GetBytes like shown above.